# Transform a list in a dictionary

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

I need to transform the list detail_flights in a dictionary. Following a part of the list (it's longer but the structure is always the same):

```
detail_flights = ['22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n12:05 – 13:45\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m']
```

I'd like to put all the information of the list in the following headers:

```
detail_headers = ['departure_time', 'departure_airport', 'to_delete', 'arrival_airport', 'type_flight', 'duration']
```

I'd like to obtain something like this:

```
detail_flights = [{'departure_time': '22:20 – 23:55', 'departure_airport': 'BGY Bergamo Orio al Serio', 'to_delete': '-', 'arrival_airport': 'BCN Barcellona-El Pra', 'type_flight': 'diretto', 'duration': '1h 35', 'departure_time': '6:20 – 8:00', 'departure_airport': 'BCN Barcellona-El Prat', 'arrival_airport': 'BGY Bergamo Orio al Serio', 'type_flight': 'diretto', 'duration': '1h 40m'}, {....}]
```

This is my code:

```
def listToString(s): 
    str1 = " " 
    return (str1.join(detail_flights))
        
detail_flights = listToString(detail_flights)
detail_flights = detail_flights.split(sep='\n')

from itertools import zip_longest
detail_headers = ['departure_time', 'departure_airport', 'to_delete', 'arrival_airport', 'type_flight', 'duration']
d1=zip_longest(detail_headers,detail_flights)
print (dict(d1))
```

And this is my output, it doesn't work correctly:

```
{'departure_time': '22:20 – 23:55', 'departure_airport': 'BGY Bergamo Orio al Serio', 'to_delete': '‐', 'arrival_airport': 'BCN Barcellona-El Prat', 'type_flight': 'diretto', 'duration': '1h 35m', None: '1h 45m'}
```

Answer (score 1):

- `Split` detail_flights by `\n` to get list of flight details.
- Use `zip` to make key,value pairs of a `dict`

```
detail_flights = ['22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n12:05 – 13:45\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m']
detail_headers = ['departure_time', 'departure_airport', 'to_delete', 'arrival_airport', 'type_flight', 'duration']

detail_flights = detail_flights[0].split("\n")
dict(zip(detail_headers,detail_flights))
```

```
>> {'departure_time': '22:20 – 23:55',
 'departure_airport': 'BGY Bergamo Orio al Serio',
 'to_delete': '‐',
 'arrival_airport': 'BCN Barcellona-El Prat',
 'type_flight': 'diretto',
 'duration': '1h 35m'}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'd like to obtain a dictionary that contains all the elements of the list detail_flights, not only the first one. Ho can I do it? Thank you really much

Answer (score 1):

```
detail_flights = ['22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n12:05 – 13:45\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m']
    
detail_headers = ['departure_time', 'departure_airport', 'to_delete', 'arrival_airport', 'type_flight', 'duration']
dictionary = dict(zip(detail_flights , detail_headers ))

print(dictionary)
```

**output:**

```
{'22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m': 'departure_time', '22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n12:05 – 13:45\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m': 'departure_airport'}
```

Comment: Thank you, but Id' like to obtain also the headers in the output dictionary